# listener for checking if value is set in extjs combobox

Tags: select, extjs, combobox, listener, store

I have a combobox which has a 'select' listener where in I do various tasks with the selected value. I also have an ADD button which adds a value to the store of the combobox and also sets the value of the combobox to the newly added value. Problem is that in this step the select listener is not invoked and as such all the tasks which I was performing in the listener are not being executed.

I need to know how to have the newly added value selected and the listener for this combobox invoked so that I can use this newly added value for the next steps.

Comment: considered listening to 'change' event instead of 'select'?

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes the easy things are the ones which befuddle me.